# spring boot restTempalte call (get Data) with security handel

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, resttemplate

i want get data from another application by calling resttempalte in springboot .. 
how to set my header for security .. how to handel security of another application

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);

System.out.println("Rest--->"+result);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like:

```
final String uri = "http://localhost:9090/TicketingSystem/caselogcontroller/getAppIds";
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
headers.set("authorization", <your tokens>));
String result = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(headers) String.class);
System.out.println("Rest--->"+result);
```

Comment: i want get data by userid and password not session token

Answer (score 0):

User [OAuth2RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2RestTemplate.html) to make authenticated REST requests with the credentials.
Following is a sample XML based configuration to get you started:

```
<bean id="oAuth2RestTemplate" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientCredentialsResourceDetails"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="defaultOAuth2ClientContext"/>
    <property name="requestFactory" ref="httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory"/>
    <property name="accessTokenProvider">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.client.ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider">
            <property name="requestFactory" ref="httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory" class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="httpsClientFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="httpsClientFactory" class="com.finity.ssl.HttpsClientFactory">
    <property name="sslKeyStorePath" value="${server.ssl.key-store:}"/>
    <property name="sslKeyStorePassword" value="${server.ssl.key-store-password}"/>
    <property name="sslKeyPassword" value="${server.ssl.key-password}"/>
    <property name="sslTrustStorePath" value="${server.ssl.trust-store:}"/>
    <property name="sslTrustStorePassword" value="${server.ssl.trust-store-password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="clientCredentialsResourceDetails" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.client.ClientCredentialsResourceDetails">
    <property name="accessTokenUri" value="${auth.service.url:https://localhost:8443/auth-service}/oauth/token"/>
    <property name="clientId" value="${auth.service.client.id:DUMMY_CLIENT_ID}"/>
    <property name="clientSecret" value="${auth.service.client.secret:password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="defaultOAuth2ClientContext" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.DefaultOAuth2ClientContext"/>
```